# Download VHD Azure

Tags: virtual-machine, vhd, azure

I have an Ubuntu server on azure but I'm out of credit and want to download the disk to my local machine.

When I go into the portal -> disks > myDisk

I can a web address to a vhd file. If I try to go to it directly it says Authentication failed.

How can I download the vhd file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to grab my VHDs.

It's a free cross platform app by Microsoft that let's you download from your storage accounts in any subscription.

[image: Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer]